# Lemma 3.1 of Stroock and Varadhan 1969

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability

In page 355 of the article Diffusion processes with continuous coefficients I (Stroock Varadhan - 1969), one finds  in lemma 3.1:

$$(3.2) \quad\mathbb{P}(\sup_{\gamma \leq u \leq t}  \vert \xi(u) - \xi(\gamma) \vert \phi \geq l  ) \leq 2d \exp \big\{- \frac{l^2}{2 A (t-\gamma)}\big\}$$

The proof provided in the sequel establishes that

$$\mathbb{P}(\sup_{\gamma \leq u \leq t}  \langle \hat\theta, \xi(u) - \xi(\gamma) \rangle  \geq l  ) \leq  \exp \big\{- \frac{l^2}{2 A (t-\gamma)}\big\}$$

where $\hat \theta = \frac{\theta}{\vert \theta \vert}$ for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

The authors say that the inequality (3.2) is immediate from this.

I can't see that cleary.

I have two observations:

1) $\phi$ is not a defined  object in the lemma nor in the previous discussion.

2) one  might guess that $\phi$ is a typo and one should read $d$ instead.

this seems promissing since 
$$\vert \xi(u) - \xi(\gamma)\vert \geq l \Rightarrow \exists i \in \{1, \ldots d\}   \sup_{\gamma \leq u \leq t} \langle  e_i, \xi(u) - \xi(\gamma) \rangle \text{ or } \sup_{\gamma \leq u \leq t} \langle  -e_i, \xi(u) - \xi(\gamma) \rangle  \big\} \geq \frac{l}{d}   ; $$

therefore one obtains

$$\mathbb{P}(\sup_{\gamma \leq u \leq t}  \langle \hat\theta, \xi(u) - \xi(\gamma) \rangle  \geq l  ) \leq \mathbb{P}\left( \exists i:\langle e_i, \xi(u) - \xi(\gamma) \rangle  \geq \frac{l}{d} \right) \leq 2d\exp \big\{- \frac{l^2}{2 A d^2(t-\gamma)}\big\}$$

where the last inequality is obtained using $\mathbb{P} (A \cup B) \leq \mathbb{P} (A) + \mathbb{P} (B)$ and the inequality established for $e_i$ and $i \in \{-d, \ldots - 1, 1 \ldots d\}$  $e_{-i} := e_i$

Still, although similar, that is not  eq (3.2).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above remarks seem to be correct:
 there is indeed a typo ($\phi $ should be a $d$) moreover, since the authors are only concerned with the the behaviour as $l^2$ goes to infinity For their purposes it suffices to assure the existence of a finite constant $A$ such that the inequality holds, that constant can be $A$ or $Ad^2$.